# I can not connect to the phone for debugging any more

Tags: android

After developing and testing for months my android application both on the emulator and on a phone, I suddenly can not connect any more to the phone in one of the two PCs I use for development. 
One PCs runs Windows XP 32bits. Here everything is ok. But my main development machine is a Windows 7 32bits: Both of them run Eclipse Galileo. I can not get connected to the Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000T phone from there. Two Sundays ago I updated my application last version to the phone. Went on vacations. After returning I upgraded the Samsung Kies suite to the new version 2. It is supposed it installs USB drivers for Windows. I also upgraded to Android SDK 9 and ADT 9 but I'm not sure it was after the problem appeared. Then I realized can not connect to the phone. My first suspect was Samsung Kies. But I made all these intallations on the xp PC and the connection works OK. Then I returned to the Windows 7. There is another driver called "USB Driver for Windows" which I have installed from Android's SDK "SDK and AVD Manager"/"Available Components"/"Android Repository" I tried to reinstall it. I deleted the package despite the warning it can not be undone. Then I tried to find it on the "Available Packages" but it was no more there.

I reinstaled Samsung Kies, Eclipse, Android SDK but the problem remains the same:
Another fact: with USB debugging active, Samsung Kies can not connect to the phone. It detects something is connected but it stays forever trying to connect.But it occurs also on the XP machine.
In summary:

- I can not get listed the "USB Driver for Windows" in the "SDK and AVD Manager"/"Available Components" for installation, even after reinstalling all the development environment
- I can not get the development environment to connect to the phone for debugging.

How to fix this?

Any hint is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.
Sammy

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the origin of the problem. I hope it will be useful to someone else.

Device Manager showed "ADB Interface" / "SAMSUNG Android Composite ADB Interface" with a warning sign. The device was not running 'cause some inconsistencies in the registry.

I deleted both the "ADB Interface" / "SAMSUNG Android Composite ADB Interface" and "Universal Serial Bus Controllers" / "SAMSUNG Android USB Composite Device" and reinstalled them from Windows Update. This time I didn't used Samsung Kies Tools / Install Driver menu.

Thanks for your time.

Sammy